# Raise bad request in Service Class, that is being called from worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a service and a worker. Calling the service from that worker.
In the service if some params are missing, 400 bad request are coming. I need to raise it in service class but that is throwing the error.

```rb
if response.success?
  log_messaging(200, response.status)
else
  raise :status => :bad_request
end
```

Whatever I am raising it, I am getting the like this:

```
TypeError: exception class/object expected
from (pry):2:in `raise'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need raise error, you need pass string or exception to `raise` method

See docs:

https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Kernel.html#method-i-raise

But you passed hash instead

For example

```rb
raise "Something went wrong"
```

or

```rb
raise ArgumentError, "Something went wrong"
```

or

```rb
raise ArgumentError.new("Something went wrong")
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't raise a bad request exception but need to render bad request status code( 422 status code).
So instead of raising you need to do

```
render json: { errors: [] }, status: :unprocessable_entity
```